# No Typelevel compiler for Scala 2.10.6

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import a Scala project that uses the [Typelevel Scala compiler](http://typelevel.org/) into IntelliJ.

This fails since a couple of dependencies cannot be resolved; this is the first of the error messages in `sbt.last.log`:

> unresolved dependency: org.typelevel#scala-compiler;2.10.6: not found

How do I fix this?

Comment: I also hit this issue, and filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as a workaround for this I commented the line in `build.sbt` that tells SBT to use the Typelevel compiler:

```
//scalaOrganization in ThisBuild := "org.typelevel"
```

Refreshing the project (`View` → `Tools` → `SBT`) leads to a neatly integrated Scala project in IntelliJ.

Afterwards I uncomment the line to use the Typelevel compiler again.